# Last Item in Query Results - PHP

Tags: php, foreach, pdo

I have a database of page names on my site, and I'd like to loop through a query and output each of these page names. I've done my query using PDO:

```
// Site Menu Items
try {
  $mds_system1 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mds_system;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT longName, shortName, `position`, standalone FROM `site-menu`";
$sitemenu = $mds_system1->query($sql);
```

I then loop through the query as so (part of a CMS to edit pages on the site):

```
    $n=1;
    foreach ($sitemenu as $item) {
        echo "<a href='?page=edit&amp;edit=".$item['shortName']."' target='_self'>";

        if ($n==count($sitemenu)) {
            echo $item['longName']."</a><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo $item['longName']."</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
        }
        $n++;
    }
```

I'd like there to not be a delimiter after the last result, and according to many examples I've seen, this code *should* work. However, the "count($sitemenu)" variable is always set to "1", no matter the number of results. Therefore, nothing really happens. Is the code that I'm attempting not possible with PDO?

Comment: Possibly stupid question: Are you sure $sitemenu is a php array?

Comment: Not 'possibly stupid' but most sensible question one ever may ask.

Comment: Note that there is no need to address table name if only one table is used. I shortened your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot one required operation.
beside just query execution, you have to get the actual results using `fetchAll()` method.
And you will get your desired array.

So, in fact your question has nothing to do with the problem in the title but rather it is basic PDO usage related.

And lack of debugging of course.
As you have to ask the question from the comments yourself, and boil the problem down to the `$sitemenu` contents.